# Can a two-variable discrete linear combination be transformed into a one-variable discrete monotonic sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, discrete-calculus

Consider, for example, the discrete linear combination
$$F(m,n) = Amn + Bm + Cn + D$$
where $A,B,C,D$ are non-zero positive integers and constants, and $m,n$ are non-negative integers and variables.

Can that be transformed in something like $G(i)$ where $G$ is the ordered sequence (strictly increasing monotonic function of $i$) of the numbers resulted from the different combinations of $m$ and $n$ evaluated on $F$?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So you need both: (A) an easy-to-describe one-to-one mapping $$i\leftrightarrow(m,n);$$ (B) the resulting $G(i)$ must be a monotonic function of $i$

Comment: I updated my question to be more precise and use the proper terminology. Thank you.

Comment: So you wanted *positive* $A,B,C,D$ and positive $m, n, i$ all along?

Comment: Yes! $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ non-zero positive integers and $m$,$n$,$i$ positive integers (including zero). I wanted to see if there was a general solution but your proof (with $A$=0 and $B$=-$C$) demonstrate the opposite. So I edited the question in order to include just non-zero positive integers for the coefficients.

Comment: "positive integers (including zero)" is better written as "nonnegative integers".

Comment: Alex, I updated my question with your last suggestion. I also included the notion that $G(i)$ must be a strictly increasing monotonic function (instead of just monotonic).

Answer (score 0):

**This answer was given before the OP question was updated**

We can construct a transformation that maps each pair $(m,n)$ to a unique index $i$, thus creating a one-to-one mapping: $(m,n)\leftrightarrow i$. Let's assume for simplicity that $m,n,i$ are nonnegative.

**Example solution:** order the pairs $(m,n)$ from smaller to larger sum values $m+n$. For equal sum values, order from smaller to larger $m$. So the ordered sequence of pairs might look like this:
$$
(0,0) \quad (0,1) \quad (1,0)\quad (0,2)\quad (1,1)\quad (2,0) \ldots
$$
In this example, the value of $i$ can be computed from $m$ and $n$ as follows:
$$
i={(m+n)(m+n+1)\over2}+m.
$$
In the other direction, the values of $m$ and $n$ can be recovered from $i$ like this:
$$
s=\left\lfloor{\sqrt{8i+1}-1\over2} \right\rfloor, 
\qquad m=i-{s(s+1)\over2}, \qquad n=s-m.
$$
Moreover, for the *particular case*
$$
A=0, \qquad B=C
$$
the above solution gives a *monotonic (sorted)* $G(i)$ sequence, i.e.
$G(i)\le G(j)$ if $i<j$.

However, in general it is impossible to satisfy the requirement that the values $G(i)$ must be monotonic (sorted). We prove this below.

**Proof of impossibility of a monotonic $G(i)$ in the general case:** 
Assume, on the contrary, that it is possible to make $G(i)$ a monotonic function for any choice of the coefficients $A, B, C, D$. Then consider
$$
A = 0, \qquad B=-C.
$$
For these coefficients, we will have
$$
F(0,0) = D, \quad F(1,1) = D, \quad F(2,2) = D, \quad F(3,3) = D, \ldots
$$
That is, for an infinite subset of pairs $(m,n)$, where $m=n$, we will have $F(m,n)=D$, so a *monotonic non-decreasing* $G(i)$ sequence will never get to any value larger than $D$ in such a situation. Thus $G(i)$ being monotonic and $G(i)$ taking all values of $F(m,n)$ are two contradictory requirements.

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you very much for the reply =). Unfortunately the answer you gave me it's not working. Consider for example the following discrete linear combination F(m,n) = 100nm+110n+30m+33. Applying your formula I'm getting: F'(0)=F(0,0)=33, F'(1)=F(0,1)=63, F'(2)=F(1,0)=143, F'(3)=F(0,2)=93. As you can see the number 93 is coming after the number 143, so the sequence is not sorted.

Comment: The requirement that the sequence $G(i)$ must be monotonic (sorted) cannot be fulfilled in the general case. I added a proof of this fact in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is for the updated question** (with positive $A, B, C, D$)

We can (in principle) construct a transformation that maps each pair $(m,n)$ to a unique index $i$, thus creating a one-to-one mapping: $$(m,n) \leftrightarrow i.$$
To do so, order the pairs $(m,n)$ from smaller to larger $F(m,n)$ values. For pairs with equal values of $F(m,n)$, order from smaller to larger $m$. Let $i$ be the ordinal number (index) of the pair $(m,n)$ in this ordered sequence of pairs. Let $G(i)=F(m,n)$, where $(m,n)$ is the pair with index $i$. Thus $G(i)$ is a monotonic function of $i$ by construction. The requirement for $G(i)$ to be *a strictly increasing monotonic function* is not realistic because, e.g. for $B=C$ we have $F(m,n)=F(n,m)$, that is, the same value of $F(m,n)$ will be encountered more than once.

This solution becomes possible for non-negative $A, B, C, D, m, n$, because each value $F(m,n)$ is taken only finitely often.

However, this solution *might not be practical* because, e.g. we do *not* (in general) have simple formulas for recovering $m$ and $n$ from a given $i$.

*Without the monotonicity requirement*, an alternative solution is to order the  pairs $(m,n)$ from smaller to larger sum values $m+n$; for equal sums, order from smaller to larger $m$. Then simple formulas for the mapping $(m,n) \leftrightarrow i$ do exist.